# Excel data layout

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I'm wanting to make a chart similar to this:

[image]

The data i'm working with is different but the concept should be the same. I'm most curious in how to group x-axis (category) values. In my case I will be grouping based on distance in feet falling into zones (i.e. 0-600 ft = zone 1). How would I need to organize the data in order to create this graph?

Answer (score 2):

I tried to re-create your example. Here is my take at it.

[image: Chart]

And here is how I created it:

- My data has three columns: Period (containing the text "1st quarter", "2nd quarter", etc.), LA Lakers and Minnesota (data values). In my example data I created a total of 20 records, 5 for each quarter. So my first column (Period) had 5 rows with "1st quarter", 5 rows with "2nd quarter", etc.) The columns with LA Lakers and Minnesota contained the values you see in the graph.
- Create the chart (line chart) and right-click the horizontal axis and select "Format axis..." The trick here is to set the "Interval between tick marks" and "Specify interval unit" to exactly the amount of datapoints you have per period.
- Left align the label text of the horizontal axis.
- Add the major vertical gridlines.

What this does, is that is creates only one label per quarter of data.

Now for some fany artwork:

- Select a nice font
- Change the background to orange
- Set the horizontal gridlines to white
- Put the legend in the top corner and give it a lighter orange color and a drop shadow
- Add boxes (ribbon: Insert, Shapes, Rectangle) for the purple and blue LA Lakers and Minnesota text blocks at the top of the chart.

It took me more or less 10 minutes to create this. Good luck with it.

Answer (score 1):

The data layout you need is shown in my tutorial [Chart with a Dual Category Axis](http://peltiertech.com/chart-with-a-dual-category-axis/). Essentially you use multiple columns for the X axis labels, with the first column having a label in the first cell of a group. Excel figures out the spacing based on the arrangement of blank cells.